# My HTML and PHP codes are not giving me the expected output

Tags: php, html

I have been trying to write a code for a guessing game. The user has to guess a random, odd number from 1-99. Here is my code-

```
<?php

$heading = "Welcome to the guessing game";
$num_to_guess = rand(1,99);
if(!isset($_POST['guess'])){
    $message= "Welcome to the guessing game";

} elseif($_POST['guess'] %2==0) {
    $message= "The number you are guessing is not odd!!!";

} elseif($_POST['guess']< $num_to_guess){
    $message= "Your guess is smaller than the secret number";

}elseif($_POST['guess']> $num_to_guess){
    $message= "Your guess is bigger than the secret number";

} elseif($_POST['guess']== $num_to_guess){
    $message= "You guessed correctly.Now try to guess another number!";
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Guessing Machine </title>
</head>
<h1> <?php echo $message; ?></h1>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
<p><label for= "guess">Try to guess the odd number between 1 and 99 </label>
<input type= "text" is= "guess" name= "guess" /></p>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="check" value="Check"/><br><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I am getting the desired output for the first four if statements. What do I do in order to get the message, "You guessed correctly! Now try to guess another number!" ?
I am very confused. If anybody could help, that would be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: you have to type `$num_to_guess` random number ?

Comment: Your chances to get th desired output are 1 in 200. Remember that each form submit yields a new random number. (Else: sessions)

Comment: @Fast Snail, yeah, a random number. but how do I get the last message?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in your code to restrict the `num_to_guess` variable from being odd. Are you not trying even numbers at all? Try printing the variable to see what value it actually is and then put in that value to see if it works.

Comment: If you want to make it easier to guess the number, change the `rand(1,99);` to `rand(1,5);` - your more likely to guess the right number and you can then check if your message comes out.

Answer (score 0):

In the php any variable destroy after page rendered,Cause you can't save the `$num_to_guess` number with usual variables. you need to set session and use more than one.

I changed your code to :

```
<?php

$heading = "Welcome to the guessing game";
if (!isset($_SESSION['g_number'])){
    $_SESSION['g_number'] =  rand(1,99);
}
$num_to_guess = $_SESSION['g_number'];
if(!isset($_POST['guess'])){
    $message= "Welcome to the guessing game";

} elseif($_POST['guess'] %2==0) {
    $message= "The number you are guessing is not odd!!!";

} elseif($_POST['guess']< $num_to_guess){
    $message= "Your guess is smaller than the secret number";

}elseif($_POST['guess']> $num_to_guess){
    $message= "Your guess is bigger than the secret number";

} elseif($_POST['guess']== $num_to_guess){
    $message= "You guessed correctly.Now try to guess another number!";
    unset($_SESSION['g_number']);
}

?>
```